Safari - How to Display the Filename After Setting File Input with JavaScript?
In Chrome and Firefox, the filename is displayed after setting a File input using JavaScript. However, Safari does not display the filename when the File input is set programmatically. It does display the filename when the file is selected manually.
Is there a way to make Safari show the filename after setting the File input using JavaScript?
Example:


const blob = new Blob(["Demo"], { type: "text/plain" });
const file = new File([blob], "demo.txt", {
  type: "text/plain",
});
const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();

dataTransfer.items.add(file);
document.querySelector('#fileInput').files = dataTransfer.files;
<input id="fileInput" type="file" />



Safari:

Chrome:


Why does it matter? It's not actually using that file, so it seems like Safari is more correct.

@Barmar, the example is simplified for illustration purposes. The key issue is user experience. I want the file input to visually indicate to the user that a file has been set programmatically. This ensures that the user is aware they can either select a file themselves or proceed with the pre-selected file. Without displaying the filename, it looks like no file has been selected, which can be confusing and lead to a poor user experience.

But it doesn't use the preselected file. It uses the contents of the Blob. It's misleading to say it's using demo.txt.

@Barmar When the form is submitted, the actual contents of the Blob will be uploaded with the filename "demo.txt". The main point is to provide a visual indication to the user that a file has been set, whether manually or programmatically. This behavior is consistent in Chrome and Firefox, improving user experience by clearly showing that a file is ready for upload. While it's debatable which approach is correct, ensuring clarity for the user is crucial.

That's a good point, Safari looks like nothing will be uploaded at all and you need to select a file first.

You can probably solve this by using a hidden file input, and displaying the selected filename in an ordinary HTML element, which you initialize with the default filename.

Solution by Rik Schennink - PQINA found here
Add JavaScript
if (fileRef.current.webkitEntries.length) {
  fileRef.current.dataset.file = `${dataTransfer.files[0].name}`;
}

and CSS
input[data-file]::after {
  content: attr(data-file);
  margin-left: 0.375em;
}

Full solution


const blob = new Blob(["Demo"], { type: "text/plain" });
const file = new File([blob], "demo.txt", {
  type: "text/plain",
});
const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();

dataTransfer.items.add(file);
const fileInput = document.querySelector('#fileInput');
fileInput.files = dataTransfer.files;

if (fileInput.webkitEntries.length) {
  fileInput.dataset.file = `${dataTransfer.files[0].name}`;
}
input[data-file]::after {
  content: attr(data-file);
  margin-left: 0.375em;
}
<input id="fileInput" type="file" />




You could just use fileInput.dataset.file = dataTransfer.files[0].name; rather than using interpolation for a single string value, but it doesn't hurt :).

@HereticMonkey True. This is copied from Rik, so I can only speculate. However, I think the template literal is used to ensure that undefined is not assigned. It can be made clearer with dataTransfer.files[0].name ?? '', but I think it is fine as is.
